# How to Monitor Subscription/Publication Traffic in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

My App resubscribes whenever there is a connection loss.
I fear this causes a lot of traffic.

Is all data resend on every subscription?

And how can I monitor this traffic?

(I tried Kadira but could not find a traffic amount tab)

Comment: Just use your browser's inspector to watch what's actually happening under these conditions. That will give you a much better appreciation for what is actually happening on the wire and what you need to optimize if anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid this kind of traffic, you should try iron-router and manage subscriptions for every template/page. This way you subscribe only to data client needs and also in case of reconnect, the usage is no different from refreshing or changing page.

In case you have a one-page app, you should publish only an amount of data user can process at the moment and increase it in case he needs more.

Kadira Debug is really good for monitoring your app, you can monitor query response time, query rate, memory usage etc. Even if that's not exactly what you're looking for, that's for sure a good place to start to see how your app connects with your db.

Comment: I just found that kadira debug also shows the detailed DDP messages (which is what I need): https://kadira.io/blog/product/introducing-kadira-debug